# repeating when send data from multi-dimensional JSON to html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

```
 const Arri = JSON.parse(data);
            var pname;
            for (var i = 0; i < Arri.length; i++) {

                 pname = " " ; // null tried
                var propinfo = Arri[i].propinfo;
                for (var j = 0; j < propinfo.length; j++) {
                   pname = pname +propinfo[j].propertyname +"  |  ";
                }
                $('#tblbody').append('<tr><td scope="row">'+Arri[i].propertyid+'</td><td>'+pname+'</td></tr>"');
            }
```

when I run this code I have the following output.

pro1 | pro2  | Pro3

pro1 | pro2  | Pro3   pro4 | pro5  | Pro6

pro1 | pro2  | Pro3   pro4 | pro5  | Pro6   pro7  | pro8   |  Pro9

pro1 | pro2  | Pro3   pro4 | pro5  | Pro6   pro7  | pro8   |  Pro9   pro10  | pro11   |  Pro12

I want to be like it:

pro1  | pro2    | Pro3

pro4  | pro5    | Pro6

pro7  | pro8    |  Pro9

pro10 | pro11   |  Pro12

Comment: plese provide html part a well. is #tblbody surounded by <table></table> tag?

Comment: you must have something like this: <table><tbody id='tblbody'></tbody></table> or <table id='tblbody'></table>

Comment: <table class="table">
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                                    <th scope="col">First</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Last</th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody id="tblbody">

                                </tbody>
                            </table>

Answer (score 1):

Have you try NULL instead of double quoutation,

```
 const Arri = JSON.parse(data);
        var pname;
        for (var i = 0; i < Arri.length; i++) {

             pname = NULL;
            var propinfo = Arri[i].propinfo;
            for (var j = 0; j < propinfo.length; j++) {
               pname = pname +propinfo[j].propertyname +"  |  ";
            }
            $('#tblbody').append('<tr><td scope="row">'+Arri[i].propertyid+'</td><td>'+pname+'</td></tr>"');
        }
```

Comment: I tired, but still get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

lets try local variables. try this:

```
        const Arri = JSON.parse(data);

        for (let i = 0; i < Arri.length; i++) {

            let pname = "" ; // null tried
            let propinfo = Arri[i].propinfo;
            for (let j = 0; j < propinfo.length; j++) {
               pname = pname +propinfo[j].propertyname +"  |  ";
            }
            $('#tblbody').append('<tr><td scope="row">'+Arri[i].propertyid+'</td><td>'+pname+'</td></tr>"');
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This code does not have any problem, I'm sure you json has problem, can you please share your json data.